# Mysql fetch value transfer to an array

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to transfer a fetch value to an array?

For example in my database table I have a column named vehicle, and inside that column, it contains:

```
vehicle1
vehicle2
vehicle3
```

All of that in one array.

Now is it possible to transfer it to an array? (array())?

Another question:
How can I echo it separately?

```
vehicle1
vehicle2
vehicle3
```

are all in one mysql array, how can I echo it one by one? Because if I echo the array the result would be the three vehicles. What I'm asking is that how can I echo the array that the result would be vehicle1 and if I echo it again, vehicle2. and so on.

Comment: There is no "array" column datatype in MySQL. Do you maybe have a newline-separated string or a serialized PHP array stored in a varchar or text column?

Answer (score 0):

```
$vehicles = array();

$sql = "SELECT `vehicle` FROM `table` WHERE 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result) {
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) !== false) {
        $vehicles[] = $row['vehicle'];
        // or
        // $vehicles[] = $row; // store all columns in vehicle array
    }
}

foreach($vehicles as $vehicle) {
    echo "{$vehicle}<br />\n";
}
```

You can also create an array of arrays to store multiple details from the result of your queries.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: That probably means that the first variable in the foreach is not an array.  Try var_dump($vehicles) and see if that helps.